# Split values from string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the string in javascript in the following format,

```
var a = "";var b ="";var c= "";
var str = "ItemID=123&Name=AO Document&Dept=Testvalue";
```

I need to split from **str** and get Itemid value in a,name value in b,Dept value c.How can I do this in javascript ?

Comment: what should a,b,c must contain as a result?

Comment: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) ?

Comment: Take your time to search before ask.  ANyway this is the code you want.   

`var a = "";var b ="";var c= "";
var str = "ItemID=123&Name=AO Document&Value=Testvalue";

arr=str.split("&");
a=arr[0];
b=arr[1];
c=arr[2];

console.log(a,b,c);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = "";var b ="";var c= "";
var str = "ItemID=123&Name=AO Document&Value=Testvalue";

// split the string at the '&' and '=' characters, but use only those parts with odd indices
var parts = str.split(/[&=]/).filter((_, i) => i % 2 === 1);

// assign the values to a, b and c using destructuring
[a, b, c] = parts;

console.log(a, b, c);
```